# Java - Check whether a string contains the same digit or not

Tags: java, regex, string, validation

I have an `int` for example:

```
151515
1
1111111
4848484
111
888
```

I need to test/check if the number contains only 1s, valid examples:

```
1
11111
1111111111
11
```

Invalid examples:

```
88888888888
8885555
4747
7
889
```

Any suggestions?
Probably any `regex`? or there is a fast solution without regex and keep the value as an int without parsing it to String.

Answer (score 10):

You can try it like this:

```
String str = String.valueOf(nums);

if (str.replaceAll("1", "").length() == 0) {
    // it contains all ones
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is only a very limited number of `int` that match, so you could do

```
if (i == 1 || i == 11 || i == 111 || ..... )
```

The compiler will tell you when to stop ("literal too large for int").

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public boolean isAllOnes(int num) {
    for (int powerOf10 = 10; ; powerOf10 *= 10) {
        if (num * 9 == powerOf10 - 1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (powerOf10 > Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

which doesn't involve regex or converting to a string, but I don't know whether it's really faster than the other answers.  (Thilo's brute force solution is probably the fastest.)

Answer (score 0):

Answer concept
1.Convert int to string first.
2. Then try this regex:

```
"^[1]*$"
```

3.by using java regexp pattern matching 
Pass the string and pattern

Comment: This will match an empty `String`. You can replace `*` with `+` to prevent that.

Comment: @Titus If he converts an integer to a string, there's no way it will be empty.

Comment: @ajb oh, yes, you're right. I didn't consider that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
String str = "1111111";
System.out.println(str.matches("^[1]+$"));
```

[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/40oGRD)